# SELinux remove extended ACL

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, selinux

I have a set of files that can't have selinux's extended acl on them.  When running ls -la I get a result similar to:

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    1 Aug  8  2014 filea
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    1 Aug  8  2014 fileb
          ^ Note the dot
```

SELinux is set to permissive, but I can't run the command `sudo setfattr -h -x security.selinux filea`, it returns the error `setfattr: filea: Permission denied`.  If I completely disable SELinux this works though.

The issue is that disabling SELinux requires a restart of the server, which isn't possible.  Is there any way to remove SELinux file ACLs (aka remove that dot in `ls -la`) without restarting the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELinux ACLs aren't set directly on the files, so no, you can't really.

All SELinux access rules are applied to "contexts"; all processes *and* all files live in one context or another, and the dot only means that the file has a *specific* SELinux context assigned to it (see `ls -Z`) as opposed to the default one (`unconfined_u:object_r:default_t`).

If the current rules allow it, you can [change a file's security context](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html) (relabel it) using **`chcon`**.